# Почему при создании bytes объекта, Python некоторые байты переводит в ASCII?

Tags: python

По непонятным для меня причинам, некоторые байты из последовательности интерпретируются Python'ом как ASCII символы, как этого можно избежать?

```
packForSend = bytes([0xFF, 0x03, 0x00, 0x6B, 0x00, 0x03, 0x76, 0x87])
packForSend1 = bytes.fromhex("6B")
packForSend2 = bytes.fromhex("FF 03 00 6B00 0003 7687")

print(packForSend)
print(packForSend1)
print(packForSend2)
```

[image: Вывод консоли VSCode]

Comment: Не переводит, а отображает (на самом деле ascii и не-ascii байты никак не различаются). Делает это, чтобы изначально текстовая строка в байтовом виде отображалась как строка, а не набор шестнадцатеричных кодов. Если вы эти байты потом куда-то отправляете - то вообще ничего не нужно делать ("избегать"), как есть - так и отправляйте.

Comment: @insolor, тогда почему именно некторые из них? а не все подряд?
И как с таким багом в Python, делать логирование пакетов и прочие?

Comment: Это не баг, а фича. Отображает как символы только те байты, значение которых совпадает с кодом какого-то символа в таблице ASCII. К примеру, байты со значением от `\x00` до `\x19` не имеют соответствующего знака (если не брать досовские кодировки во внимание), поэтому они ни в какой символ не "превращаются". То же самое с байтом `\xFF`. Если вам нужно отображение каждого байта в 16-ричном виде - используйте например метод hex: `b'abcde'.hex()` превратится в `'6162636465'`. Или используйте функцию [hexlify](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) из модуля `binascii`.

Comment: При отображении литерала питон стремится отобразить его в как можно более удобном для человека виде, вот и отображает символы для соответствующих кодов. На содержимое байтовой строки это никак не влияет: `b'k'` и `b'\x6b'` это одно и то же, хранится в памяти одинаково и при сравнении равно друг другу, просто две разные формы записи одного и того же значения

Comment: @andreymal, я это понимаю. Просто меня как Embedded разработчика, работавшего до этого с языком Си, возмутило что Python "без моего разрешения" предпренимает какие-то самостоятельные дийствия.

Comment: @DmitrijBudejkin, ну в Си же вы когда выводите массив байт через printf не возмущаетесь, почему Си самовольно отобразил эти байты как символы? Для вывода набора байт приходится целый цикл городить, каждый байт отдельно отображать в hex виде. А тут почему-то удивляетесь, почему print пытается отобразить данные в человекочитаемом виде.

Answer (score 0):

@insolor, я Вас понял, Вы предлагаете перед выводом в консоль, конвертировать весь пакет данных в шестнадатиричную строку, и только потом выводить в консоль. Таким образом я буду получать свои hex значения

```
packForSend  = bytes([0xFF, 0x03, 0x00, 0x6B, 0x00, 0x03, 0x76, 0x87])
packForSend1 = bytes.fromhex("6B")
packForSend2 = bytes.fromhex("FF 03 00 6B00 0003 7687")

debugPrint  = packForSend.hex()
debugPrint1 = packForSend1.hex()
debugPrint2 = packForSend2.hex()

print(debugPrint)
print(debugPrint1)
print(debugPrint2)
```

@insolor, спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли)